# Loading screen before <head>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I would like to load the following svg, which is absolutely positioned in the middle of the screen, before the head tag.
I've got a lot of css and other javascript, and I want to show the loading screen before anything else.

Is this possible?

**CSS:**

```
html body svg#circle-loader {
    position: absolute; float: none; clear: both; top: 50%; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 50%;
    width: 50px; height: 50px; margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
    -webkit-animation: spin 1s linear infinite; -moz-animation: spin 1s linear infinite; animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}

@-o-keyframes spin { 100% { -o-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }

html body svg#circle-loader circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 187; stroke-dashoffset: 50;
  stroke: rgba(26, 60, 88, 0.9);
  -webkit-transform-origin: center; -moz-transform-origin: center; -ms-transform-origin: center; transform-origin: center;                   
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<svg id="circle-loader" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 66 66" preserveAspectRatio="xMixYMid meet">
        <circle class="path" fill="none" stroke-width="8" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="28"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: why don't you create another div which overlays your content by using a higher z-index which contains the SVG, and then dismiss that when the page is loaded? This should be in your body tag, objects outside of  `body` make for bad markup

Comment: @Alex In order to get to the loading screen, It'll have to go through the head tag. Load all the CSS and javascript. And only then move to the body and load the div.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't load a css/js file first?

Comment: @Michael, That and the js take a bit to load...

Comment: Place your animation on the top of your `body` and its necessary css in the `head`. Place the css includes in the `head` and the js includes at the bottom of `body`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your body you could wrap the SVG in a div first off.

As you may have quite a big CSS and jQ file for the rest of your document, you could set up a CSS and jQuery file specifically for your loader and put them into your header so that they load first (as they will be small in size). This would be better practice than placing the CSS/jQ inline.

Set up your CSS loader file with whatever is needed and set the z-index to be higher than the other elements on the page, e.g.

```
#loader {
background: #FAFAFA;
z-index: 1000;
}
```

Then set up your jQ file so that once everything else is loaded in the page you will remove the loader div, e.g.

```
$(window).load(function() {
$('#loader').css({'display':'none');
});
```

**UPDATE**

Instead of using display none you could do it less abruptly by using this :

```
$(window).load(function() {
$('#loader').hide("slow");
});
```

Comment: Is there any way I can force a div to load before anything else (possibly with inline css with) Javascript?

Comment: In your html you should place your div at the very top, directly under your body tag, this will achieve this.

Comment: What if I used `load_js();`?

Comment: Are you refering to the https://github.com/rkitover/load-js script? If so yes you could, but you can do it more efficiently by placing the loader css/jq in the header and then the rest of the css/js in the footer. This would mean that your loader and the page content will load first, then your bigger files will load at the end. Then once everything is loaded, the .hide will come into play and reveal your page. Plus, doing it this way would save you loading another script.

Comment: I should note however that loading the other css in the footer is technically invalid but will still work. How big is your biggest css file, and would it be a big problem to keep that in the header too and just place the larger JS files in the footer?

Comment: Well...I have everything inside <style> in head. Contains the css to all elements. Some of which will be echoed by php, based on whats requested. So the loading screen will be default, and will appear every time the page is reloaded, regardless of what the php echoes. If that makes sense.

Comment: I've decided to go with what you suggested. Seem like a better option I think. I will hide the loader and show the body this way `$(window).load(function() {
 $("#cont-load").css("display", "none");
 $("#cont-load").fadeIn(800);
});`

Comment: This seems like the best option dude, thanks for accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would place the svg css inline on top of `head`, followed by the css file includes, the svg code on top of `body`, and all the javascript file includes at the bottom of `body` (where they should be):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>... the svg css, inline ... </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="... other css files ...">
     :
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      ... your svg html ...
    </div>
    ... page content ...
    <script src="... js scripts ..."></script>
     :
  </body>
</html>
```

And then, once everything is fully loaded, discard or hide the svg.

PS. I'm going to steal your nice animation :)

Comment: Enjoy the animation :)